# Installing Windows Builder in eclipse

Tags: java, windowsbuilder

I want to install Windows Builder in eclipse, but when the installation is done it requires you to restart eclipse, will this delete my past procjects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be afraid.Nothing won't happen with your projects by restarting eclipse.I recommend you to don't using WindowBuilder.Try it,but creating JFrame and swing apps are better if you creating them by your self.